# JFrame is too small and pack() isn't working

Tags: java, jframe, window-resize

So I have two JFrames. The first one just has a button with an Event to call the second one. This second JFrame contains a table filled with data from a MySQL database, which is the following code:

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame {
    public NewClass()
    {
        ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB";
        String userid = "root";
        String password = "password";
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password );
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ))
    {
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        while (rs.next())
        {
            ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
            }

            data.add( row );
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }

    Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
    Vector dataVector = new Vector();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
        Vector subVector = new Vector();
        for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
        {
            subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
        }
        dataVector.add(subVector);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ )
        columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));

    JTable table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)
    {
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    NewClass frame = new NewClass();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

When I run NewClass directly, pack() works as is supposed to and resizes the JFrame depending on the size of the talble that's within. However, whenever I run the first JFrame with the button and then press the button to call the event, NewClass pops up but the window is way too small. I have tried using setSize and obviously pack().

When I resize the JFrame manually the columns and rows are all there like they're supposed to, it's just that I can't figure out why pack() isn't working.

Do you have any ideas on how to resize this second JFrame without having to do it manually?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The code for the button on first JFrame which calls NewClass is the following:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    NewClass frame = new NewClass();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"However, whenever I run the first JFrame with the button and then press the button to call the event, NewClass pops up but the window is way too small"* - What button? What action?

Comment: "So I have two JFrames. The first one just has a button with an Event to call the second one." - Just another JFrame with a button, its only job is to call the second JFrame (NewClass).

Comment: [The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) . Did you set any ?

Comment: @ACZepp Okay, so since that's where the problem seems to be, perhaps you should have provided that code as well, so we can see how you're creating and showing this second frame

Comment: @MadProgrammer apologies, I added the code for the button that is on the first JFrame. Thank you!

Comment: @c0der I tried using "buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));"  to set the preferred size on the JPanel but I get the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change...

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    NewClass frame = new NewClass();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

to something more like...

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    NewClass frame = new NewClass();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

which would seem to match what you're doing in your `main` method